# field values as columns from master detail in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

i got two tables in a master-detail relation and want to select all data in a single select query.

table "person":

```
id;name
1;Allen
2;Bert
3;Chris
```

table "connectivity":

```
id;personId;type;value
1;1;phone;+123456789
2;1;mail;allen@allen.allen
3;2;mail;bert@bert.bert
4;3;phone;+987654321
5;3;fax;+987654322
```

The query output should be something like

```
person.id;person.name;phone;mail;fax
1;Allen;+123456789;allen@allen.allen;
2;Bert;;bert@bert.com;
3;Chris;+987654321;;+987654322
```

Any idea possibly without writing some function?
It should dynamically add the colummns when the detail-table is extended. E.g. adding a row to the detail table like

```
6;2;icq;0123456789
```

My prefered solution would fit into a select-query.

Thanks!
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add columns to a static SQL query.

The model you are using is called "Entity–attribute–value model". You can google for details on its different implementations.

The only "easy" way (I can think of) to have many dynamic properties per object in SQL is to dump them all into a single structure like HSTORE, JSON(B), BLOB... In this case the output will loke like:

```
id;name;params
1;Allen;{"phone":"+123456789", "email":"allen@allen.allen"};
2;Bert;{"email":"bert@bert.com"};
3;Chris;{"phone":"+987654321", "fax":"+987654322"};
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your answer, it gave me a hint for my solution. I decided to work with arrays. seems for me to be the closest way.
For whom it may concern: I used a subquery within the columns and the array() function.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JOIN and a CASE to select the values you need. Something like this:

```
SELECT  person.id,
    person.name,
    CASE connectivity.type WHEN 'phone' THEN value END AS phone,
    CASE connectivity.type WHEN 'mail' THEN value END AS mail,
    CASE connectivity.type WHEN 'fax' THEN value END AS fax
FROM    person
    JOIN connectivity ON person.id = connectivity.personId;
```

Offtopic: Don't use a mix of UPPER and lower case, PostgreSQL only uses lower case unless you put everything between "double quotes".

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 p.name,
 phone.value phone,
 mail.value mail
from person p
left join connectivity phone on phone.personid = p.id and phone.type = 'phone'
left join connectivity mail on mail.personid = p.id and mail.type = 'mail'
```